# Floating UIView on UITableView broken in iOS6

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiview, scrollview, ios6

In my app i have UIView that floats at the top of a UITableView (Visualise:Attached to the bottom of the navigation Bar), under iOS5 i was enabling it to float at the top using these lines of code in **scrollViewDidScroll**

```
// get the table and buttonView bounds

CGRect tableBounds = self.tableView.bounds;

CGRect buttonViewFrame = self.buttonView.frame;

// make sure the buttonView at the table's original x and y as the content moves 

self.buttonView.frame = CGRectMake(tableBounds.origin.x,tableBounds.origin.y,buttonViewFrame.size.width,buttonViewFrame.size.height);
```

This however no longer seems to work in iOS6, does anyone know why or how to fix the problem? I'm supporting iOS5 and above.

Having looked through the iOS6 release notes i found this...

> Note that you can make a subview of the scroll view appear to float (not scroll) over the other scrolling content by creating constraints between the view and a view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as the scroll view’s superview.

How would I set this up in code as Im not using AutoLayout in storyboards as I'm still supporting iOS5. It would also be great if anyone can enlighten me as to why the code i was using in iOS5 no longer works in 6.